# How do I add a .cs file to a project template in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2012

In the same way that Program.cs is always attached to a new project, how do I add an additional file to be included in a new project as part of the project template?

This is the project template I am trying to add it to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\ConsoleApplication

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

You will need to create a project based on the template you want to edit.  Then use the Export Template to overwrite the original template.

## Longer Answer

[How to: Update Existing Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)